# Semantic-ui's LESS files are missing

Tags: css, html, less, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-css

First I downloaded semantic-ui then I tried an npm install but none of them created less files. How to I get semantic-ui's less files and does semantic-ui only uses less and not sass and stylus?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We're happy to help with programming problems, but please do your research first :) Semantic-UI's source stylesheets are written in LESS. It's in the `src` directory. Semantic-UI's readme includes links to LESS-only versions. Googling `semantic-ui sass` turns up doabit's Sass port

Answer (score 0):

I have googled it for you: `semantic ui less files`

I found this results:

- https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-LESS

it contains package.json with name: `semantic-ui-less`

## solution

`npm install semantic-ui-less --save`